# Can't get jquery $ajax to call .NET MVC 2 controller method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery

I'm new to jquery and ajax - just can't seem to get this to work!  See my related question: [Use Json and AjaxLink to Toggle Link Values in ASP.NET MVC 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444852/use-json-and-ajaxlink-to-toggle-link-values-in-asp-net-mvc-2)

Here's my jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("div[id^=add]").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        updateMe(this.id.split('_')[1], "AddRequirement");
    });

    $("div[id^=remove]").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        updateMe(this.id.split('_')[1], "RemoveRequirement");
    });
});


function updateMe(myId, myAction) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "AgreementType.aspx/" + myAction,
        data: 'aId=' + <%:Model.AgreementType.Id%> + '&rId=' + myId,
        dataType: "text",
        error: function(request, msg){
            alert( "Error upon saving request: " + msg );
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Currently I have a two different divs.  A foreach loop determines which one to display:

```
<%if(req.Agreements.Any(r => r.AgreementTypeId == Model.AgreementType.AgreementTypeId))
    {%>
        <div id="<%:string.Format("remove_{0}", req.Id)%>" class="divLink">Remove</div>
    <% }
    else
    { %>
        <div id="<%:string.Format("add_{0}", req.Id)%>" class="divLink">Add</div>
    <%{%>
```

Here's my controller action.  Pretty simple:

```
    public JsonResult AddRequirement(string aId, string rId)
    {
        string result = "Remove";
        //Code to add requirement

        return this.Json(result);
    }


    public JsonResult RemoveRequirement(string aID, string rID)
    {
        string result = "Add";
        //Code to remove requirement

        return this.Json(result);
    }
}
```

All the success function needs to do it update the innerHtml of the target with the contents, and change the id to match.  Seems so easy!  And yet I can't seem to figure it out.  TIA

Comment: I'd prefer to just return a simple text string, which is why the controllers are JsonResult and the $ajax datatype is "text"; the controllers used to just return a string object.  I've been tweaking this code for a while...

Comment: Thia line def looks wrong: url: "AgreementType.aspx/" + myAction Can your post your routing data from your global.asax? I am 100% you need to remove the .aspx from that line.

Comment: Nope, it's right.  I had to add the .aspx in the routing so MVC would run on IIS 6:             routes.MapRoute(
                        "Default", // Route name
                        "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally - the code that works.  This will allow the user to click on a div which will call a different controller method based on the contents of that div, in effect allowing you to toggle toggle elements of the object in a foreach loop.  I'm sure it could be improved upon; for instance, I probably don't need to get the value of the div from the controller method, but at least it works.

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("div[class^=toggleLink]").click(function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();

            var divText = $('#' + this.id).text();

            if (divText == "Remove") {
                updateMe(this.id, "Remove");
            }
            else if (divText == "Add") {
                updateMe(this.id, "Add");
            }
        });
    });


function updateMe(myId, myAction) {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/AgreementType/" + myAction,
        data: "aId=<%:Model.AgreementType.Id%>&rId=" + myId,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result.success) {
                $('div#' + myId).text(result.value);
            }
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
            alert(req + " " + status + " " + error);
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Add(string aId, string rId)
    {
        //Add to the template

        string result = "Remove";
        string nClass = "remLink";

        return Json(new { success = true, value = result, newClass = nClass });
    }


    public ActionResult Remove(string aID, string rId)
    {
        //Remove from the template

        string result = "Add";
        string nClass = "addLink";

        return Json(new { success = true, value = result, newClass = nClass });
    }
```

**Markup**

```
<% foreach(var req in std.Requirements)%>
   <% { %>
   <tr>
       <td>
       <%if(req.Agreements.Any(r => r.AgreementTypeId == Model.AgreementType.Id))
       {%>
           <div id="<%:req.Id%>" class="toggleLink">Remove</div>
       <% }
       else { %>
           <div id="<%:req.Id%>" class="toggleLink">Add</div>
       <%} %>
```